# Print a String Before a Get-ChildItem Value

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following command to count the number of files by file type in a directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Folder" -Recurse -File -filter *.heic | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

Sample output:
32

That works fine, but how can I print some text before the value to make it more meaningful? Something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Folder" -Recurse -File -filter *.heic | Measure-Object | Write-Output "Number of HEIC files: " + %{$_.Count}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can print some text before the value to make it more meaningful?

Given that `Measure-Object` keeps count of all the objects it's iterated through before passing it to the pipeline, you can use a simple string concatenation to your `Count` property inside your loop with `"Number of HEIC files: " + $_.Count`:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Folder" -Recurse -File -filter *.heic | 
    Measure-Object | 
    % { "Number of HEIC files: " + $_.Count }
```

...but, if you wrap your command inside the grouping operator `(...)`, you're able to collect all the files upfront as an array of file objects and use the arrays `Count` *intrinsic* property to measure it for you:

```bash
"Number of HEIC files: " + 
    (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Folder" -Recurse -File -Filter '*.heic').Length
```

Comment: Nicely done; quibble: For arrays - and other collection types - the `.Count` property is the [`System.Collections.ICollection.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ICollection.Count) property, even if that interface implementation is an _explicit_ one, as in the case of `Array` (which in C# would require a cast to the interface, but PowerShell surfaces even explicit interface implementation as direct members).
`.Count` is only an intrinsic property on instances of types that do not natively have it, as evidenced by  `Get-Member Count` producing _no_ output.

Comment: @mklement0, so `Length` is a better approach than `Count` when it comes to performance due to the `PSObject` wrapper that makes `Count` available? Whereas all arrays have a `Length` property and not all `Collections`  have `Count` one?

Comment: I would expect use of (native) `.Count` (via an explicit interface implementation) to only incur a _negligible_ performance impact, _if at all_ - and a few quick tests seem to confirm that. I'd say it's not worth worrying about.